# What exactly is the carrier phase in a RINEX file?

Tags: phase, gps, gnss

RINEX files are containers for preprocessed data in GNSS receivers. I want to know what exactly the 'carrier phase' means. As far as I can tell, the carrier phase is simply the phase (that is, a value between 0 and 2pi) of the carrier signal emitted by the satellite. However, carrier phase measurements in RINEX files seem to be recorded as large numbers and I don't understand what that measurement is. This screenshot of a RINEX 2.11 observation file seems to denote that the first L1 carrier phase observation for the G12 space vehicle is 16073 - what does that mean?
[image]